# Sharepoint -- Get the difference between two SPListItemCollection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

We have a requirement where the items of a Sharepoint list that the user does not have access to must still be visible to the user in the front-end, with the option to "Request Access" if necessary. To do this, we have a web service that first fetches all the items from the list, and next fetches only those items that the user has access to.

```
// Get all the items in list
SPUser superUser = SPContext.Current.Web.AllUsers[@"SHAREPOINT\SYSTEM"];
SPUserToken superToken = superUser.UserToken;
SPList superList;
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url, superToken))
{
    using (SPWeb elevatedWeb = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        superList = elevatedWeb.Lists.TryGetList(listname);
    }
}
SPListItemCollection superListItems = superList.GetItems(camlQuery);


// Get items in list accessible to current user
SPUser regularUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
SPUserToken regularToken = regularUser.UserToken;
SPList regularList;
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url, regularToken))
{
    using (SPWeb regularWeb = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        regularList = regularWeb.Lists.TryGetList(listname);
    }
}
SPListItemCollection regularListItems = regularList.GetItems(camlQuery);
```

Next, the difference between the two list-item-collections needs to be computed. This should've be simple enough, if this were possible:

```
// Now make a list of the items that the current user DOES NOT HAVE ACCESS TO
SPListItemCollection noAccessListItems;
foreach (SPListItem superListItem in superListItems)
{
    if(!regularListItems.Contains(superListItem)) // Fails here
    {
        noAccessListItems.Add(superListItem);
    }
}
```

The only problem is that `SPListItemCollection` does not support a `.Contains()` method.

**What is the best way to get the difference of the two list-item-collection objects?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Cast to use all IEnumerable LINQ methods like Contains().
Using try-catch for this is not too pretty solution, imho.
You can do it in one simple line:

```
var noAccessListItems = regularListItems.Cast<SPListItem>().Where(x => !superListItems.Cast<SPListItem>().Select(y => y.ID).Contains(x.ID));
```

Or like this:

```
var noAccessListItems = regularListItems.Cast<SPListItem>().Except(superListItems.Cast<SPListItem>());
```

But in this case you must define comparer for SPListItem.

**UPDATE1:**

To define comparer you need implement class inherited from IEqualityComparer like this:

```
class SPListItemEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<SPListItem>
{
    public bool Equals(SPListItem i1, SPListItem i2)
    {
        return i1.ID == i2.ID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SPListItem item)
    {
        int hCode = item.ID;
        return hCode.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you need add instance of this class as second argument in `Except` method:

```
var noAccessListItems = superListItems.Except(regularListItems, new SPListItemEqualityComparer());
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems like a neater solution. Can you elaborate on the performance of the LINQ solution vs try-catch? Also, it would be good if you showed how a comparer for SPListItem can be written.

Comment: @SNag, it's not about performance (I don't think it's really much difference). It's about code readability at most. Updated my answer to include comparator code snippet.

Comment: Thanks again! If it's about readability, then IMO the LINQ is much harder to read than the try-catch. The comparer solution is the best though. I've given you an up-vote and accepted your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Got it working. This works:

```
// Now make a list of the items that the current user DOES NOT HAVE ACCESS TO
SPListItemCollection noAccessListItems;
foreach (SPListItem superListItem in superListItems)
{
    try
    {
        regularListItems.GetItemById(superListItem.ID);
    }
    catch(ArgumentException ae)
    {
        noAccessListItems.Add(superListItem);
    }
}
```